# How to get fields name from Django QuerySet, even when it's an empty set?

Tags: python, django, pandas, django-queryset

A cool binding between Django and Pandas is the ability to construct a `DataFrame` directly from a `QuerySet` using:

```
queryset = models.A.objects.filter(...).annotate(...)
frame = pd.DataFrame(queryset.values())
```

Which wonderfully works as long as there is at least one record returned by the `QuerySet`.
Acting at the `QuerySet` level is interesting because there we can have the benefit of all annotations as well as native columns.

But this method will return a totally empty `DataFrame` (without columns defined), let's say from something like:

```
queryset = models.A.objects.filter(id__lt=0).annotate(...)
frame = pd.DataFrame(queryset.values())
```

The DataFrame is totally empty:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []
```

While we want something like instead:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: ["id", "key", "prop1", ...]
Index: []
```

Where columns names are preserved in order to get this frame able to merge with another frames seamlessly.

The pandas way to do this is to force columns names at the `DataFrame` creation using the `columns` switch.

```
queryset = models.A.objects.filter(...)
frame = pd.DataFrame(queryset.values(), columns=queryset.get_fields())
```

Unfortunately it seems that this `get_fields` or similar is not implemented or obvious at the first glance for the `QuerySet` object.

I already know that I can fetch column names from a `QuerySet` that `exists()` using this dirty one:

```
frame = pd.DataFrame(
    queryset.values(),
    columns=queryset[0].__dict__.keys()
)
```

But, indeed it will not works for an empty `QuerySet`.

I also know that I can get model columns as follow:

```
frame = pd.DataFrame(
    queryset.values(),
    columns=[item.name for item in queryset.model._meta.get_fields()] + [...]
)
```

But then I miss all annotation columns created by the `QuerySet` or will require to encode it manually which is what we want to avoid.

I have the feeling that somehow `QuerySet` may know about all the columns it should return. At least it should know it after the query execution execution as the empty SQL Result Set will definitely contains the column names and types.

So my question is: **How to get fields name from Django QuerySet, even when it's an empty set?**

That's not a problem if the construction is a bit bizarre or convoluted as long as it allows to fetch annotation column names as well.

Comment: Take a look at [django-pandas](https://github.com/chrisdev/django-pandas). From the [code](https://github.com/chrisdev/django-pandas/blob/master/django_pandas/io.py#L86-L126) it's seems properly handling fieldnames for all Django versions.

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this:

```
fields = [item.name for item in queryset.model._meta.get_fields()] + [item for item in queryset.query.annotations.keys()]

frame = pd.DataFrame(
    queryset.values(*fields),
    columns=fields
)
```

I found this solution while debugging the `queryset` object. It has a property called `query` which points to this class [`Query`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/0ec60661e61b153e6bcec64649b1b7f524eb3e18/django/db/models/sql/query.py#L171)'s instance. In the `Query` class, there is a property named [`annotations`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/0ec60661e61b153e6bcec64649b1b7f524eb3e18/django/db/models/sql/query.py#L265). This property contains all the annotation information. You can use that to get all the annotated fields.

Comment: Yes I know it, but I may not have access to it when I actually get the QuerySet transformed into DataFrame.

Comment: I did some debugging, and I came up with a solution which is updated in the answer.

Comment: I came with this `[item.attname for item in queryset.model._meta.fields]` for model fields in order to get the `_id` which is used in `value()`. Thank you for your help.